# How to pass the current Instance(sender) of xaml(view) into ViewModel

Tags: mvvm-light

I need the instance of view in viewmodel to manipulate the element of view from ViewModel. how can I pass the instance of current View (sender) to ViewModel.

```
<UserControl...>
    <br>...<br>
    <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Width="100" Height="30" 
        Content="Remove" Margin="5" Visibility="Hidden"  
        Command="{Binding CellFrame.WidgetRemoveCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
    <br>...<br>
</UserControl>
```

This passes the instance of viewModel in WidgetRemoveCommand. How to pass the Intance of Usercontrol.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, you can simply bind the Command property in constructor of user control. Have a locator class which keeps pointer to CellFrame view model.

```
btnRemove.Command = some_locator_class.static_method.WidgetRemoveCommand;
btnRemove.CommandParameter = this;
```

The CellFrame view model can have a RelayCommand named WidgetRemoveCommand like below:

```
RelayCommand<CellFrame> WidgetRemoveCommand
```

Now, this relay command has delegate method defined like below:

```
public void WidgetRemoveAction(CellFrame cell)
{
    // here you get it! 
}
```

So, the trick is to send the 'this' in command parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: way to totally circumvent MVVM Sir.  You have successfully undermined the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, when the parent view creates the child view, have it inject a "remove" command into the view model at creation time as below.

```
//Parent
var model = new ChildControlViewModel();
var view  = new ChildControl(model);
Children.Add(view);
model.RemoveCommand = ()=>Children.Remove(view);
```

Obviously this is massively simplified, also I'd make sure that you have a view control factory that ties up to a viewmodel, even having this in the code behind seems... wrong to me.

Also, you can use the messenger and register for messages alternatively which IS an acceptable way to notify the view of the view model's action.  For instance, I use this to register view->view interactions for a zoom slider in one of my projects.  This approach COULD be used for removal.

```
    public FlickrPhotoBrowserViewModel()
    {
        Photos = new ObservableCollection<FlickrPhotoViewModel>();
        Messenger.Default.Register<ZoomChangedMessage>(this, message => ImageSize = message.Content);
    }
```

When I create a photo:

```
    public async Task CreatePhotoContainerAsync(string photoID, IImageSearchService searchService, IStreamService streamService)
    {
        if (photoID != null)
        {
            var Photo = new FlickrPhotoViewModel(photoID);

            Photo.ShowDetailsCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                FlickrPhotoDataViewer.ShowPhoto(photoID, searchService, streamService);
            });



            // REMOVE CODE!!! ^_^
            Photo.RemovePhotoCommand= new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                Photos.Remove(Photo);
                FlickrPhotoDataViewer.CleanupPhotoElement(Photo);
            });
            // REMOVE CODE!!! ^_^


            //update async collection from bound UI thread
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => Photos.Add(Photo));

            var target = await searchService.GetPhotoThumbnailUriAsync(photoID);

            Photo.ImageStream = await streamService.GetStreamAsync(target);

            Debug.WriteLine("Image Download Complete " + target);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Image NULL " + photoID);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example MVVM Light has an option to pass EventArgs with the command. In EventArgs there is sender and from that sender (parent etc) you can search the tree.

But anyway not very good idea to mess with view in viewmodel. I would place the logic in View's code behind, it's just fine.

Comment: agree with @Robert: mvvm-ViewModell should not reference any view-item

Comment: There are a few cases in which this acceptable, but only as a last resort, and ONLY for performance scenarios.

Comment: yes indeed direct dependency of view in viewModel is not good practices. but some time we need to manipulate intense GUI in viewmodel.

Comment: what if U want to save Selected Item Path of TreeView in ViewModel? :)